# Error: RPC failed; HTTP 302 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 302

Tags: git, http, ubuntu, curl

When I executed the git clone command, I got the the following error.

```
Error: RPC failed; HTTP 302 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 302
```

The error always happened in case of Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04, but The error didn't happen in case of Ubuntu 16.04.

I don't know the difference Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04/20.04.

Could you please give me some advice me?

Comment: Code 302 is a "found" redirect: the URL responds saying "don't look over here, look over there ---> instead". *Git* won't follow this for security reasons. You should follow it manually instead, **checking** it first to make sure you believe it's valid. (The bug in Ubuntu 16.04 was that Git accidentally followed the redirect, which means you might get sent to some bad guy's repository.)

Comment: Thank you for you advice.
I tried to redirect manually by adding the below to .gitconfig.

```
[url "https://:aaa.com/"]
    insteadof = https://bbb.com/
```

But the same error has happened again.
What could be the cause?

Comment: The `insteadOf` has to list the exact prefix, e.g., `insteadOf = https://bbb.com/` if you're using https.